# Change direction of input type="datetime-local to RTL

Tags: html, css

I have tried to change its direction using direction:rtl in CSS and dir="rtl" as an attribute but in vain.

```html
<input type="datetime-local">
```

[image]

Comment: what outcome do you expect? applying `direction: rtl;` works fine for me

Comment: I recently stumbled across a related question: Which locale setting is used for date formats in date inputs? There might be differences between browsers and platforms. Number formats can be set different to the main locale in Firefox and will overwrite the document’s locale, afaik. Windows allows setting number formats independent from language as well.

Comment: @tacoshy calendar icon should go to left side and date input right side.